# Buffered Block Convolution Using Overlap-Save

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing, fft, convolution

So, I'm currently implementing the overlap-save method of block convolution in matlab, and having some trouble doing so.

My implementation is using a buffered input in order to do real-time processing of input data in vectors. The input is fed to an instance of my overlap-save class, and once the buffer is full with more input than the pre-defined block length (greater than the filter length), input is processed in chunks (size of the block length) using the standard overlap-save algorithm until the length of the data in the buffer is less than the block length. Then it sits and waits for more data to come in and repeats the process.

Now that all seems to be working fine, but the issue is in flushing the buffer after all the input has been passed to the class. There is always less data in the buffer than the block size when the flush method is called, and I'm having trouble processing the remainder of the data.

It should also be worth noting that after the class processes normal data, it keeps the last N-1 (where N is the filter length) data points from the input in the buffer to uphold the "overlap" portion of the algorithm for subsequent data or the final flush.

My question I guess is how should I process the remaining data in the buffer when flush() is called? I tried simply zero-padding and convolving it with the filter, but that produces garbage output... Any suggestions?

Note: the output of flush should be appended to the output of processing the normal data blocks and this new output should match the output of conv(input, filter) in matlab.

Comment: SOLVED by playing whack-a-mole

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question, so I'll phrase a very general answer.  The very concept of flushing means that your input has come to an end.  When you decide how you want your processor to behave after your input signal is finished, you can code it.  Zeros is a common approach, so I can only suspect that your attempt at zero-padding (which I think is the right answer) had some other flaw.  Or perhaps your signal simply ended at a peak, and zero-padding introduced a sharp transition.  In that case, repeat the last value might be a better solution than zero-padding.